# A cow is an animal vs The cow is an animal—which is correct and why?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

After more than ten years of learning English, I still have a few problems with articles.
Which of the following two sentences is correct and why?

> A cow is an animal.

or

> The cow is an animal.

Comment: Some examples using each would be helpful to give a good explanation. Otherwise, the answer is simply "Both".

Comment: may this will be useful http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34815/the-confusion-between-the-or-a-article

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uses of the definite article (the) in generic noun phrases](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22647/uses-of-the-definite-article-the-in-generic-noun-phrases)

Answer (score -2):

Both can be considered correct, depending on the situation. "A" and "an" are considered *indefinite* articles. Therefore, when you say "a cow" or "an apple", you wouldn't have a definite/particular cow or apple in mind. "The" is a *definite* article. Therefore, when you say "the cow", you would have a definite/particular cow in mind.

In some sense, though, my answer is over-generalized. The sentence "the cow is an animal" could also refer more generally to the taxonomical genus to which cows belong. However, even this would still be a definite use of "the" because you have a particular genus in mind.

Comment: *Therefore, when you say "the cow", you would have a definite/particular cow in mind* - sorry, but that is not correct.  [The definite article is often used when referring a whole class of things of the same type](https://www.englishgrammar.org/definite-article/), for example ["The lion (Panthera leo) is one of the big cats in the genus Panthera..."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion)

Comment: @stangdon, I'd think so, too, but then conversely it should be the animal?

Comment: "there is a cow in the room", still means a (edit: or the) particular cow.

Comment: @Hectorvon - No, "the cow is an animal" is fine, because **the cow** (example of a class of things) is **an animal** (a singular but nonspecific animal).

Comment: @stangdon I'd be more apt to say that my answer is incomplete, rather than incorrect, but either way, thank you for the feedback. I've made a correction that I believe reflects your intention.