# "connect artist and listener" VS "connect artists and listeners""

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> 1. A STEINWAY intimately connects **artist and listener**, and invites its owner to join a tradition of musical perfection, making it an invaluable investment.
> 2. A STEINWAY intimately connects **an artist and a listener**, and invites its owner to join a tradition of musical perfection, making it an invaluable investment.
> 3. A STEINWAY intimately connects **artists and listeners**, and invites its owner to join a tradition of musical perfection, making it an invaluable investment.

I am confused about which form will the words artist and listener should take? What are the differences.

Comment: You missed out the relatively common permutation *...connects **the** artist and **the** listener* - and the relatively *uncommon* (but still perfectly valid) plural version *...connects **the artists** and **the listeners***. Effectively these are all stylistic choices. See the earlier question [The confusion between “The” or “A” article](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/34815/126) for more background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence appears in the piano manufacturer's and suppliers' literature and I think it is a stylistic choice.

The third sentence works quite well and is grammatically correct.

Your second sentence seems vague, as if it won't attract much of an audience.

But the first sentence is for advertising, and was perhaps chosen to be direct and punchy. The nouns "artist" and "listener" are used almost like proper names, and it generates more of a sense of immediacy, of **perfomance**, which is what the product is for.

Comment: If I, not the lauded brand, write such a sentence in an exam,  will I be punished for poor command of English grammar? Or will I be given extra credits for being stylish?

Comment: Well, unless you are asked to write advertising copy... I would use your third sentence.